# Basic Auth with JAX WS SOAP client

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, basic-authentication, jaxws-maven-plugin

I'm trying to get Basic Authentication to work with my JAX WS SOAP Client but can't seem to get it right.

I've set up basic auth on my server machine in IIS.
I've confirmed that it works with SOAPUI from my client machine by adding `Autherization: Basic <code>` to the HttpHeaders in SOAPUI

However, in my web service client it won't work:

```
    SOAPService port = super.getPort(new QName("http://schemas.xxx.com", "SoapWebService12"), SOAPService.class);
    // Set up the Map that will contain the request headers.
    Map requestCtx = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
    requestCtx.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
    requestCtx.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "pass");
```

Then, when calling

```
    port.method(...);
```

I get a java.io.IOException: Authentication failure.

Is this enough, or have I missed to add something in this code snippet?

Comment: Logically this should be it, and it should work, try seeing HTTP headers via some proxy pass and see if authentication header set properly.